# Power.t.test error

Tags: r, statistics

When I run power.t.test I get error when SD is lower than 2. To make it worse, when I run this in a loop, it makes rest of the results 0.

[image: Output image]

Can somebody please explain me what the issue is and how to workaround it?

```
power.t.test(#n=10,
             power=.95, 
             sig.level=.05, 
             sd=  1.069045,
             delta =91, 
             alternative = "two.sided",
             strict = FALSE
            )  

Error in uniroot(function(n) eval(p.body) - power, c(2, 1e+07), tol = tol,  : 
  did not succeed extending the interval endpoints for f(lower) * f(upper) <= 0
In addition: Warning message:
In qt(sig.level/tside, nu, lower.tail = FALSE) : NaNs produced
```

Comment: trying to determine n.

Answer (score 3):

You're running into some internal trouble (which I haven't completely diagnosed yet, and which *might* be considered a bug, although it might also be a case of "just don't do that").  The problem is that your resulting required sample size is **too low** for `power.t.test` to find reliably.  Internally, `power.t.test` uses a call to `uniroot(..., interval=c(2,1e7))` to try to find the sample size - that is, it's trying all values between `n=2` and `n=1e7` (which ought to cover all realistic cases!).  It does *try* (as you can see below) to extend the search region if necessary, but it clearly can't always manage in extreme cases.

The reason the rest of the values in your table are zero is that the `for` loop stops running when you hit the error.  You can try something like

```
for (...) {
    pp <- try(power.t.test(...))
    if (inherits(pp,"try-error")) {
        ## set stuff to NA
    } else {
        ## set stuff to values extracted from pp
    }
}
```

(there are more sophisticated ways to catch the error using `tryCatch()`, but this is what I usually do ...)

```
f <- function(sd) {
  pp <- try(power.t.test(power=.95,sig.level=.05,
         delta =91, sd=sd,
         alternative = "two.sided",
         strict = FALSE
        ),silent=TRUE)
   if (inherits(pp,"try-error")) return(NA)
   else return(pp$n)
}   
f(1.4)   ## 1.382
f(1.37)  ## 1.38
f(1.36)  ## NA
```

I question whether this is a practical problem (other than the loop stopping); if `power.t.test` fails in this way then you know that the required sample size is **less than 1.38** -- i.e. ridiculously small for any real situation.